# Counting incidences from one data frame, entering results into a different data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames:  `households` and `individuals`.

This is `households`:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:5), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

This is `individuals`:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), Yesno = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

I'm trying to to add a new column to `households` that counts the number of times variable `Yesno` is equal to 1, grouping results by `ID`.

I have tried

```
households$Count <- as.numeric(ave(individuals$Yesno[individuals$Yesno == 1], households$ID, FUN = count))
```

`households` should look like this:

```
ID  Count
1   2
2   3
3   0
4   2
5   1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1: In base R

Using `merge` and `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Yesno ~ ID, merge(households, individuals), FUN = sum)
#  ID Yesno
#1  1     2
#2  2     3
#3  3     0
#4  4     2
#5  5     1
```

### Option 2: With `dplyr`

Using `left_join` and `group_by`+`summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(households, individuals) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(Count = sum(Yesno))
#Joining, by = "ID"
## A tibble: 5 x 2
#     ID Count
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     2
#2     2     3
#3     3     0
#4     4     2
#5     5     1
```

### Option 3: With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(households)
setDT(individuals)
households[individuals, on = "ID"][, .(Count = sum(Yesno)), by = ID]
#   ID Count
#1:  1     2
#2:  2     3
#3:  3     0
#4:  4     2
#5:  5     1
```

---

### Sample data

```
households <- structure(list(ID = 1:5), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))

individuals <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L,
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), Yesno = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-17L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R approach using `sapply` is to loop over each `ID` in `households` and subset that `ID` from  `individuals` and count how many of them have 1 in `Yesno` column.

```
households$Count <- sapply(households$ID, function(x) 
                   sum(individuals$Yesno[individuals$ID == x] == 1))

households
#  ID Count
#1  1     2
#2  2     3
#3  3     0
#4  4     2
#5  5     1
```

The `== 1` part in the function can be removed if the `Yesno` column has only 0's and 1's.

Comment: Thank you! This works better and makes more sense to me (I'm a novice and I haven't had time to study dplyr or data.table), however it's also much slower.

Comment: @Werner *"This works better and makes more sense to me (I'm a novice and I haven't had time to study dplyr or data.table), however it's also much slower."* Just to clarify, the very first solution I gave in my answer is base R.